# Should I allow or deny helpd file to establish connection in my Firewall on Mac OSX 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, firewall

As in the subject line. Should I allow or deny helpd file to establish connection in my Firewall on Mac OSX 10.8.5?

I would appreciate answer to that and more elaborate answer what exactly "helpd" file really is. I've browsed and browsed thru the net asking that question and getting all sorts of different answers.

Thank you all for your answers in advance!

Krešo

Answer (score 0):

helpd is the daemon that connects to the online help system on Apple's servers.

It's safe to allow through the firewall.